# Implicit DataTemplate doesn't work

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Why does the following implicit `DataTemplate` not work? Only the commented inline `DataTemplate` will work.

Note: If I remove both `DataTemplate`s, I see a string representation of the `ProductListView` full type name.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="vm:ProductListViewModel">
    <v:ProductListView/>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" TabStripPlacement="Left">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>     
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
    </DataTemplate>        
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value}">

        <!--ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="vm:ProductListViewModel">
            <v:ProductListView/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate-->

      </ContentPresenter>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) requires the use of `x:Type` as the property's type is `Object`, so if you type `DataType="ns:Type"` you set it to the string `"ns:Type"`. If the property's type were `Type` (as with [`Style.TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) for example) the XAML processor would automatically convert that `string` to a `Type`.

Thus here you should write:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductListViewModel}">
    <v:ProductListView/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

*(The property type is `Object` to allow data-templating of XML data, see the documentation for more information on that)*