# Changing Views to Grandchild causes Import Cardinality Mismatch Exception

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

Need a little assistance with the Exception thrown in the Question Title.

Firstly I know the modules that is causing the issue - just not why!

Currently refactoring an application to WPF using MVVM (using MEF as DI)
I won't allude to knowing alot about any of these (trying to play catch up on the Tech curve)

The issue that I am trying to solve 
Changing of Views based on ViewModle Selected (Parent, child and Grandchild lvl viewmodels)

Entry point of the application (MainViewModel is the application lvl ViewModel)

```
 main.DataContext = ObjectBase.Container.GetExportedValue<MainViewModel>();
```

Extract from the MainViewModel

```
 [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Exposed property for the view model exposed to the parent view
    //TODO: add a property for each view that will be exposed
    #region MEF Imports
    [Import]
    public TablesViewModel TablesViewModel { get; private set; }

    //[Import]
    //public EditTableViewModel EditTableViewModel { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    ViewModelBase _CurrentViewModel;
    //private ViewModelBase _SelectedViewModel;
    IServiceFactory _ServiceFactory;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainViewModel(IServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        _ServiceFactory = serviceFactory;
        LoadDashViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLoadDashViewCommand);
        LoadTablesViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLoadTablesViewCommand);
        LoadAdminViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnLoadAdminViewCommand);
    }
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return base.CurrentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_CurrentViewModel != value)
                base.CurrentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentViewModel, false);
        }
    }
```

The relevant code that causes the Exception

```
        //[Import]
    //public EditTableViewModel EditTableViewModel { get; private set; }
```

I an not sure if I am on the right track here, but what I would like is the following.

MainViewmodel calls the TablesViewModel from a button click (working as Intended). For the purpose of brevity I have left out the implementation of the Event handlers

```
        private void OnLoadTablesViewCommand(object obj)
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new TablesViewModel(_ServiceFactory);
    }
```

Then based on what table is selected in the TablesViewModel the EditTablesViewModel is Called and the Main View changes to reflect that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Kind Regards,
Stephen

Comment: What is the case for using MEF? Not that it's evil or anything, but it does add complications that may not be strictly necessary in your case.

Comment: None at all Ed. It was presented as part of a Tutorial. I was just looking to see how I could extend the information and patterns that were presented to fit what I would like to achieve. I have had a brief look at AutoFac

Comment: If there's no requirement to use MEF, by far the simplest way to change views based on a selected viewmodel is [implicit datatemplates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8109401/424129). Then just expose a `ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel` property and bind to a ContentControl: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />`. Raise `PropertyChanged` when `CurrentViewModel` changes, and it should work. WPF is more than complicated enough even when you do things in the simplest possible way.

Comment: Thanks for the Comments Ed. Sadly at this point the App is very dependant on MEF for DI and loose coupling. I already had all the mechanisms you mention in place and this was working - using MEF to do the resolution - just not to the Grandchild ViewModel lvl